# Return the mean() for a column for rows in DF with highest value in adjacent column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate the mean of a column in a Dataframe for the rows with X highest values in the same Dataframe. Have been trying and searching for hours without luck.

```
summary_percent_df

          TTM_Si     TTM_F       Rev_Met    price
ticker              
AVP      -0.082571  -7.927108   -2.287786   0.000000
HELE     0.005513   1.542568    1.244480    0.629727
IPAR     -0.024999  -1.611722   -0.309357   0.705969
NUS      -0.049710  0.664017    0.208076    0.656487
REV      -0.016126  -4.113906   -1.297464   0.218214
```

I want to return a single mean() value of the "price" column for the 3 stocks that have the highest value in the "TTM_Si" Column. I have come close using groupby() with .head() but having an issue sorting the data after having unstacked it for the groupby.

Comment: Do you mean something like `summary_percent_df.nlargest(3, 'TTM_Si').price.mean()    # 0.51797`?

Comment: Yes that did it. Thank you so much. I couldnt find that syntax anywhere in any of the documentation. That was so simple and clean.

Comment: You  could also try `df.sort_values(by=['TTM_Si'], ascending = False).head(3).price.mean()`